iPhone 8 Plus microphone when calling only sending an echo
I have an iPhone 8 Plus here with the latest iOS 16 version (last one supported).
Since today when making a call I can only hear myself, but the caller on the other side doesn't hear anything.
Also recording a voice message is only a flat line.
As I can hear myself as an echo during the call, I assume the microphone is fine.
Things I tried so far:

Reset network settings
Factory Reset and reinstalling the backup
Opening up the device and checking for broken cables or not plugged in connections (seems all fine)

Happy for any suggestions.
